# Prove that a function mapping to Sobolev space is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Let $Q:(0,\infty) \to W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $Q(\lambda)$ is the unique solution of:
$$-
\nabla^2 Q(\lambda) +  \lambda Q(\lambda) =f \space\space\space\space\space a.e. \text{in $\mathbb{R}^n$}
$$
Prove that Q is continuous in $(0,\infty)$ and that $\lim_{\lambda \to 0}Q(\lambda)$ exists in $W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Here $W^{k,p}$ denotes Sobolev spaces.